# Julia DataFrames equivalent of pandas pct_change()

Tags: dataframe, julia

Currently, I have written the below function for percent change calculation:

```
function pct_change(input::AbstractVector{<:Number})::AbstractVector{Number}
    result = [NaN]
    for i in 2:length(input)
        push!(result, (input[i] - input[i-1])/abs(input[i-1]))
    end
    return result
end
```

This works as expected. But wanted to know whether there is a built-in function for Julia DataFrames similar to pandas [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) which I can use directly? Or any other better way or improvements that I can make to my function above?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very specific function and is not provided in DataFrames.jl, but rather TimeSeries.jl. Here is an example:

```
julia> using TimeSeries, Dates

julia> ta = TimeArray(Date(2018, 1, 1):Day(1):Date(2018, 12, 31), 1:365);

julia> percentchange(ta);
```

(there are some more options to what should be calculated)

The drawback is that it accepts only `TimeArray` objects and that it drops periods for which percent change cannot be calculated (as they are retained in Python).

If you want your custom definition consider denoting the first value as `missing` rather than `NaN`, as `missing`. Also your function will not produce the most accurate representation of the numbers (e.g. if you wanted to use `BigFloat` or exact calculations using `Rational` type they will be converted to `Float64`). Here are example alternative function implementations that avoid these problems:

```
function pct_change(input::AbstractVector{<:Number})
    res = @view(input[2:end]) ./ @view(input[1:end-1]) .- 1
    [missing; res]
end
```

or

```
function pct_change(input::AbstractVector{<:Number})
    [i == 1 ? missing : (input[i]-input[i-1])/input[i-1] for i in eachindex(input)]
end
```

And now you have in both cases:

```
julia> pct_change(1:10)
10-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
  missing
 1.0
 0.5
 0.33333333333333326
 0.25
 0.19999999999999996
 0.16666666666666674
 0.1428571428571428
 0.125
 0.11111111111111116

julia> pct_change(big(1):10)
10-element Array{Union{Missing, BigFloat},1}:
  missing
 1.0
 0.50
 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333391
 0.25
 0.2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000069
 0.1666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666609
 0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428547
 0.125
 0.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111113

julia> pct_change(1//1:10)
10-element Array{Union{Missing, Rational{Int64}},1}:
   missing
 1//1
 1//2
 1//3
 1//4
 1//5
 1//6
 1//7
 1//8
 1//9
```

with proper values returned.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting these alternatives. Since we are dealing with number types, isn't it better to use NaN instead of missing in the custom function?

Comment: There are two considerations. First, not all number types support `NaN` and additionally for type stability it would be best if you used `NaN` of an appropriate type - of course this is not important if you want to use `Float64` in the end anyway. The second consideration is that e.g. `0/0` produces `NaN` so you cannot distinguish "missingness due to absence of data" vs "missingness due to a result of arithmetic operation". Again - if this is not important to you, you can use `NaN` as you propose. In that case the operations will be a bit faster (~10% from my experience).