# Is there any Percentage change method in JuliaDB

Tags: julia, juliadb

Is there any JuliaDB method that calculates the percentage change between timestamps.If not a JuliaDB lag method will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some flexibility here, take differences in the logarithm of your variable between timestamps instead of the percent change per se. This will be essentially the same as the percent change if your variable isn't experiencing dramatic swings, but it will be more meaningful.

Comment: find the solution from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325202/julia-dataframes-equivalent-of-pandas-pct-change